# Unary operator precedence in java

Tags: java, operators

Now, according to [this](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) website, *Unary post-increment* has more precedence than *Unary pre-increment*. I presume it meant, that `x++` is done before `++x`.

However, when tried with the following expression, I've faced problems

```
int var1=10; 
int b= --var1 + ++var1 + var1++;
```

Now, if `var1++` executes first, then according to me,

```
b = --var1 + ++var1 + 10
```

Now, if I think it should do `++var1` before `--var1`, as it mentions that the Associativity is *Right to Left*.  I suppose, it means do *things on right, before the ones on the left*

This, However, doesn't give the correct answer. The Correct Answer is `29`, while I get `33`. Why is it so ?

Comment: Expressions are evaluated from left to right, regardless of precedence.

Comment: @assylias then what does *Associativity* actually mean. I understand in case of `+,-,/. *` it is left to right, but the website says right to left for unary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I presume it meant, that `x++` is done before `++x`.

No, it doesn't mean that. I've [previously blogged](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/04/21/precedence-ordering-or-grouping/) about how I find viewing precedence in terms of execution order is problematic. It may well be valid in a computer-science-strict way, but it ends up confusing people.

I find it *much* easier to think about it as grouping. Likewise I think it's easiest to think of associativity as like precedence, but for operators of equal precedence. Evaluation order is *always* left-to-right.

So this:

```
int b = --var1 + ++var1 + var1++;
```

is grouped as if it were written:

```
int b = (--var1) + (++var1) + (var1++);
```

That's then equivalent to:

```
int b = ((--var1) + (++var1)) + (var1++);
```

(Due to binary `+` having left-to-right associativity.)

That's then effectively:

```
int tmp1 = --var1;       // tmp1 = 9, var1 = 9
int tmp2 = ++var1;       // tmp2 = 10, var1 = 10
int tmp3 = tmp1 + tmp2;  // tmp3 = 19
int tmp4 = var1++;       // tmp4 = 10, var1 = 11
int tmp5 = tmp3 + tmp4;  // tmp5 = 29

int b = tmp5;            // b = 29
```

... which confirms what you've observed.

Of course, you should always try to avoid having code as convoluted as this in the first place...

To demonstrate the evaluation order part, consider this expression:

```
int result = a() + b() * c();
```

Precedence means that's *grouped* as:

```
int result = a() + (b() * c());
```

That's equivalent to:

```
// Evaluate LHS of +, which is just a()
int tmp1 = a();

// Evaluate RHS of +, which is b() * c()
// First evaluate LHS of *, which is b()
int tmp2 = b(); 
// Next evaluate RHS of *, which is c()
int tmp3 = c();
// Now we can evaluate *:
int tmp4 = tmp2 * tmp3;

// Now we can evaluate +:
result = tmp1 + tmp4;
```

As we're executing methods, we can observe that execution order really easily:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int result = a() + b() * c();
    }

    public static int a() {
        System.out.println("a()");
        return 3;
    }

    public static int b() {
        System.out.println("b()");
        return 4;
    }

    public static int c() {
        System.out.println("c()");
        return 5;
    }
}
```

That prints:

```
a()
b()
c()
```

... which confirms the execution order shown in my expansion.

Comment: if I do `5+5*5`, then `5*5` is executed before. When operator precedence works here, then why not in my case ?

Comment: @Shashwat: Let's make it simpler to reason about: if you have `a + b * c` then `a` is evaluated, then `b * c`. To evaluate `b * c`, first `b` is evaluated, then `c`. You can see this really easily by making it `a() + b() * c()` where each method prints out that it's being executed.

Comment: @Shashwat: I've expanded my answer to include your multiplication-and-addition case.

Comment: Your example certainly cleared things up. However, the website says `x++` has more precedence than `++x`, How do we account for that ? Is there any example which proves this, because till now, I haven't found one.

Comment: @Shashwat: I don't think that ever becomes relevant, because `++x++` isn't a valid expression. If it were, however, it would be equivalent to `++(x++)` due to precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The sum `--var1 + ++var1 + var1++` translates to:

```
9 + 10 + 10
```

since the various vars are changed as the sum is processed; obviously var1++ increments after the value is used, and ++var increments before it is used.  The final value of var1 would be 11.

Comment: the answer is `29`. Yours adds up to `33`